# Multiple rsyncs in parallel using xargs - most efficient directory structure to pass through

Tags: bash, optimization, database-migration, rsync, xargs

I'm doing a database migration and I was wondering the most efficient way to pass a directory structure to xargs to run, lets say 5, rsyncs in parallel

what I have now is something like:

`find /san/mydb -maxdepth 1 | xargs -n1 -P5 -d "\n" -I% rsync -avLuR % myserver.com:/migratedData`

which lists the directories under /san/mydb (with full path),

but would it be more efficient to run:

`echo /san/mydb | xargs n1 -P5 -d "\n" -I% rsync -avLuR % myserver.com:/migratedData`

or am I misunderstanding something?

Would the second option be the equivalent of running one rsync on `/san/mydb`, or five in parallel for every file under `/san/mydb`?

**EDIT**

Worth noting that before, I was passing a list of every file under `/san/mydb` to xargs, however the output seemed to me like it was performing them sequentially rather than 5 at a time, I could be wrong though.

Comment: could you answer your own question with your solution? From your comment on the answer from @Oliver Gaida I see you found the right syntax for `find`. I'm doing `find ../source_dir/ $1 -type f | xargs -n1 -P8 -d "\n" -I% rsync -avu % ./backup/ > backup.log 2>backup.err &` dropping your `-R` flag from `rsync`. But still not sure if it's running efficiently. Did you test parallel vs serial?

Answer (score 0):

rsync will do a recursive copy. you just need:

```
rsync -av /san/mydb/ myserver.com:/migratedData/
```

Options:

- `-a` archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
- `-v` verbose

you could add the `-z` option for compress.

Comment: That will execute a recursive copy of the directory alright, but will it run 5 copies at a time?

Comment: only one copy at a time. i believe it will use the full bandwith so it does not matter.

Comment: to find the bottleneck of throughput you may use `iostat` with `-xd 1 5` for disk IO, or `sar -n DEV 1 5` for network statistics.

Comment: If I have a lot of small files (<200Kb) it will matter, as you would need to run many rsyncs in parallel to take full advantage of the available bandwith

Comment: did you check with `iostat` and `sar` ? Could you show the output, while 1 rsync job is runing?

Comment: I'm actually aware of our bottleneck, a roughly 400 Mbps connection,

Turns out my worry is unfounded, using `find $1 -type f` and piping result into xargs with `d "\n"` runs it in parallel

Comment: last time i did a rsync with many small files, my bottleneck was the disk io. did you check with `iostat -xd 1 5` . these tools a part of sysstat package... `apt install sysstat`.

Comment: @Thaufeki could you answer your own question with your solution?